# Why is np.where(...)[-1] not returning the last element in the array

Tags: numpy

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2])

result = np.where(my_array==2)

print(result[-1])
```

Result: `[1 9 12]`
Expected: `12`

Why is  `result[-1]` not giving me the last element?

Answer (score 1):

[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is returning an `ndarray` in a tuple:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2])  
>>> np.where(a == 2) 
(array([ 1,  9, 12], dtype=int64),)
```

What you want is to get the first element, which is the `ndarray`, and then return the last element of that array:

```
>> np.where(a==2)[0][-1] 
12
```

Comment: of course, thank you.